# How do I disable click-drag-click behavior in blender?

Tags: 3d-view

I am used to moving things with "click-drag-release" (holding down the mouse button and releasing it at the desired location).

How can I get Blender to emulate that kind of behavior?

(right now i have to click, then move, then click again) I wish to instead just hold down the mouse button.

Comment: If you just hold the mouse while dragging, Blender will do what you want already.

Comment: @someonewithpc with the RMB that is...

Comment: The reason I added "python" was that all other tags where unavailable. It says I need 200 reputation points or something. Seems really stupid but Im new to this site..

Answer (score 4):

Go to *User preferences*, open *Input* tab, find *3D View* > *3D View (Global)* rollout.

Now scroll almost all the way down, until you find *Translate* (the one that uses *tweak* as a key-binding instead of *keyboard*).
Open that rollout and enable *Confirm on release* checkbox.

Comment: Note that you could just search for that *Translate* rollout by changing search filter to *Key-Binding* and typing "tweak".

Comment: For Blender 2.9 it's Input > Mouse > Relase Confirms

Answer (score -4):

This appears to be caused by a bug; however, it works fine if you change your preferences to select with the <kbd>LMB</kbd> instead.

To do this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, to open the *User Preferences* and then under the *Editing* tab, set *Select with* to *Left*. Now the select and 3D cursor buttons will be reversed.

Comment: No, it happens either way. However, I found that dragging from inside the center reticle (the one in the center of the object) gives the desired behavior. 
That being said, I still would like to change this so that I never have to click to exit "move mode"